# How to create a pattern for multiple similar pages in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am making a travel website and will therefore have to create several trip pages like this one : https://ready-japan.com/ninja-adventure/
I want to find a way to have a "pattern page" for all trips, where I would just fill out the trip info from the admin panel for each trip. That would not only help me make new pages more quickly, but also allow me to modify all pages at once if I need to, rather than having to change them one by one everytime I want to add a section.

I am using an up-to-date version of Wordpress.
I tried using various travel plugins, but it wasn't very satisfactory as I can't edit the page however I want.
I also thought of using templates, but I couldn't figure out how to make templates with parts that are editable from the admin panel.

To sum it up, I want to have a general pattern and trip info for each trip being modifiable independently.
I am open to whether using a plugin or meddling with the wordpress files (as long as it's not too technical).
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a page builder like Elementor or Beaver. I, personally, use Elementor...

https://elementor.com/

Comment: Thank you but I haven't seen any function in Elementor to bulk edit all the pages that were made based on the same template. If there is one, please let me know how to use it (maybe with an add-on?).